# Flash / Flex virtual tour of room

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to make a virtual tour of a room in Flash / Flex.

How can this be achieved?

Firstly, is it enough to have pictures taken from a still point?
If yes, how can I turn them into a real tour?

Also, is there a library for this kind of thing for AS3?

Thank you.

Comment: There are several open source and commercial libraries available. See www.flashden.com for some.

Answer (score 1):

Would [PanoSalado](http://os.ivrpa.org/panosalado/) be suitable ?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently tried http://www.vtility.net

its cloud based and free. seems pretty good, but I couldn't do all that I wanted with it